# Fast subtraction of two dataframes ignoring indices (Python)

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe

How do I subtract 2 dataframes ignoring indices, in the **fastest** way possible.

E.g., I want to subtract:

```
d1=
      x1
0 -3.141593
0 -3.141593
0 -3.141593
1 -2.443461
1 -2.443461
```

from

```
d2 = 
      x2
1 -2.443461
2 -1.745329
3 -1.047198
4 -0.349066
2 0.349066
```

What I have tried:

I can do it like this, e.g.:

```
dsub = d1.reset_index(drop=True) - d2.reset_index(drop=True)
```

However, I want to do the subtraction in the most efficient way possible. I have been looking around for an answer but I have only seen solutions that do not account for speed.

How do I accomplish this?

---

**EDIT** Based on some answers, here are some times by running on my machine:

For smaller dataframes:

Method 1 (a and b):

```
a: d1.reset_index(drop=True) - d2.reset_index(drop=True)
b: d1.reset_index(drop=True).sub(d2.reset_index(drop=True))
~1024.91 usec/pass
```

Method 2:

```
d1 - d2.values
~784.79 usec/pass
```

Method 3:

```
pd.DataFrame(d1.values - d2.values, d1.index, ['x1-x2'])
~653.82 usec/pass
```

For very large dataframes please see @MaxU's answer below.

Comment: try this: `d1 - d2.values`

Comment: @MaxU Wouldn't that return a numpy.array? It would have to be converted back to a DataFrame if that's the desired output. Edit: Missed your edit, nvm!

Comment: @beeftendon, yes, thank you! I've corrected my comment and added a demo in my answer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you can do it this way:

```
d1 - d2.values
```

or:

```
d1.x1 - d2.x2.values
```

Demo:

```
In [172]: d1 - d2.values
Out[172]:
         x1
0 -0.698132
0 -1.396264
0 -2.094395
1 -2.094395
1 -2.792527

In [173]: d1.x1 - d2.x2.values
Out[173]:
0   -0.698132
0   -1.396264
0   -2.094395
1   -2.094395
1   -2.792527
Name: x1, dtype: float64
```

Timing for bigger DFs:

```
In [180]: d1 = pd.concat([d1] * 10**5, ignore_index=True)

In [181]: d2 = pd.concat([d2] * 10**5, ignore_index=True)

In [182]: d1.shape
Out[182]: (500000, 1)

In [183]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(d1.values - d2.values, d1.index, ['x1-x2'])
100 loops, best of 3: 4.07 ms per loop

In [184]: %timeit d1 - d2.values
100 loops, best of 3: 3.99 ms per loop

In [185]: d1 = pd.concat([d1] * 10, ignore_index=True)

In [186]: d2 = pd.concat([d2] * 10, ignore_index=True)

In [187]: d1.shape
Out[187]: (5000000, 1)

In [188]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(d1.values - d2.values, d1.index, ['x1-x2'])
10 loops, best of 3: 19.9 ms per loop

In [189]: %timeit d1 - d2.values
100 loops, best of 3: 14 ms per loop

In [190]: %timeit d1.reset_index(drop=True) - d2.reset_index(drop=True)
1 loop, best of 3: 242 ms per loop

In [191]: %timeit d1.reset_index(drop=True).sub(d2.reset_index(drop=True))
1 loop, best of 3: 242 ms per loop
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the added time tests for super large frames... interesting. So is this the quickest we can do? :)

Comment: @denvar can you share why a single operations that takes 4ms on decent sized input is an issue?

Comment: @Jeff good question :), sure: I am wrapping this around a Monte Carlo routine which can end up taking millions of steps. 4 ms adds up.

Comment: you can simply use numpy or numba then and avoid the construction overhead entirely

Comment: Well, the dataframe is used in other parts of my program as well. My understanding is that dataframes are handling data pretty quickly. But maybe you are right that for this particular application the cost up front of converting to a numpy array is worth it. Good suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

```
dsub = pd.DataFrame(d1.values - d2.values, d1.index, ['x1-x2'])

dsub
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder how this would work if we have multiple columns in both dataframes?

Comment: the `['x1-x2']` I used for the `columns` parameter is quite arbitrary.  leave it off, or set it to `d1.columns`.

Answer (score 0):

There's already a built-in DataFrame subtraction method. Take a look at [DataFrame.sub](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html).

The usage in your example would basically be:

```
dsub = df1['x1'].reset_index(drop=True).sub(df2['x2'].reset_index(drop=True))
```

If the DataFrames have the same column headers, then you don't need to specify the columns, e.g.

```
dsub = df1.reset_index(drop=True).sub(df2.reset_index(drop=True))
```